# Update user meta after one hour

Tags: events

With the standard wordpress function I am trying to update user meta data, but after one hour, not directly. I am doing something wrong but I can't really put my finger on it. Time is set to 30 secs for testing purposes btw.

```
 $afteranhour = update_user_meta( $user_id, 'money', $oldmoney-$totalprice);

 function do_this_in_an_hour($afteranhour) {

 // do something
 }
 add_action( 'my_new_event','do_this_in_an_hour' );

 // put this line inside a function, 
 // presumably in response to something the user does
 // otherwise it will schedule a new event on every page visit

wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 30, 'my_new_event' );

// time() + 3600 = one hour from now.
```

Comment: Can you point me... you gonna update in one hour a user with `$user_id` by the meta value *money* which is a difference betwean `$oldmoney` and `$totalprice` ? correct?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I'm trying to accomplish @OlegButuzov

Answer (score 1):

Please read carefully about [wp_schedule_single_event](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event) in Codex. As you can see, there is a third argument `$args`.

You can schedule a singule `WP_Cron` event by modifying the function you use above and passing arguments as third parameter:

```
<?php
// Your basic hook schelduling...
wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 30, 'user_cron_event', 
    array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'oldmoney' => $oldmoney,
        'totalprice' => $totalprice
    )
);
```

and your base action in this case...

```
add_action('user_cron_event', 'user_cron_event_callback');
function user_cron_event_callback($args){
    update_user_meta( $args['user_id'], 'money', $args['oldmoney']-$args['totalprice']);
}
```

Comment: Messed about with the code, but it really doesn't seem to work. Any pointers?

Comment: Of this doesn't work - no pointers...

Comment: Okay. Cron seems to be created but the user_meta just isn't updated. I'll figure it out I guess.